# Antonyms of duty is right?

Tags: grammar, subcontinental-english

I saw duty's antonyms is right.
How is it sir/ma'am kindly explain

Comment: The question of whether duty has an opposite is a matter of philosophy, not English. If you mean *failing to carry out a duty*, that might be "negligence" or "dereliction". If you are looking for a *synonym*, I suggest you consult a thesaurus. In all cases, your question is currently too short and unclear to answer: please [edit] it to provide more detail and avoid closure. Another useful site in the SE network is [ell.se]. :-)

Comment: @Chappo The OP is right, though. Please do your research.

Comment: Please [edit] to include more information. At first glance, "duty is right" is an odd thing for which to seek an antonym. On second reading, it wasn't clear which antonym(s) of duty you considered to be "right" (and which to be "wrong"). Your intended question about *having the right to do something* being in some sense an inverse of *having the duty to do the same thing* is easily lost. Some examples would help.

Answer (score 2):

*Duty* could be viewed as an antonym of *right* in the context of law, because [Salmond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Salmond_(judge)) teaches us that one of the important characteristics of a Legal Right is that:

> It avails against a person, upon whom lies the correlative duty.

In [other words](http://lawsofland.blogspot.com/2016/11/jurisprudence-unit-iv-rights-persons.html):

> Whenever law ascribes duty to a person, a corresponding right also
>   exists with the person on whom the duty is imposed.

Comment: I'm not convinced that *right* is an **antonym** of *duty*: the relationship doesn't seem to be oppositional but rather *correlative*.

Comment: @Chappo Is *credit* an antonym of *debit*?

Comment: I've referenced your answer in my own. Interesting question - would be fun to see what they'd make of it on other relevant sites like [Law.SE] and [Philosophy.se] :-)

Answer (score -1):

No, *duty* and *right* aren't antonyms. To explain why, a bit of background is necessary.

Firstly, what does each word (in the noun form) mean?

### [duty](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/duty)

> 1 : conduct due to parents and superiors : RESPECT [*"filial duty and obedience"* — John Locke]
>
> 2a : obligatory tasks, conduct, service, or functions that arise from
>   one's position (as in life or in a group) [*"was his duty to support his family"*]
>
> 2b(1) : assigned service or business [*"was put on kitchen duty"*]
>
> 2b(2) : active military service [*"returning from duty overseas"*]
>
> 2b(3) : a period of being on duty [*"report for duty at 7 a.m."*]
>
> 3a : a moral or legal obligation [*"felt it was their duty to help"*]
>
> 3b : the force of moral obligation [*"will be ready when duty calls"*]

### [right](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/right)

> 1 : qualities (such as adherence to duty or obedience to lawful
>   authority) that together constitute the ideal of moral propriety or
>   merit moral approval
>
> 2 : something to which one has a just claim: such as
>
> 2a : the power or
>   privilege to which one is justly entitled [*"his right to decide"*]
>
> 2b(1) : the interest that one has in a piece of property —often used
>   in plural [*"mineral rights"*]
>
> 2b(2) rights plural : the property interest possessed under law or
>   custom and agreement in an intangible thing especially of a literary
>   and artistic nature [*"film rights of the novel"*]
>
> 3 : something that one may properly claim as due [*"knowing the truth
>   is her right"*]
>
> 4 : the cause of truth or justice.

Secondly, what exactly is an antonym?

### [antonym](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antonym)

> : a word of opposite meaning [*"The usual antonym of **good** is
>   **bad**."*]

So, the difficulty is that while **duty** and **right** both derive from a set of social values and expectations, they don't appear to be *opposite* in meaning. As [another answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/468580) suggests, the relationship instead seems to be *correlative*. In other words, where a **right** exists on the one hand, a corresponding **duty** may arise on the other (and vice versa). Instead of being opposites (like *light* and *dark*), they're more like complementary perspectives of the same civil construct.

It's a bit like *health* and *happiness* being correlated, whereas *health* and ***sickness*** are antonyms (opposites).

One final test is to look up antonyms for *duty*. This [thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/duty) lists 16 antonyms for *duty*, but "right" isn't listed. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/duty) also lists 16 antonyms, but again, "right" is missing.

It seems clear, therefore, that **right** and **duty** are *not* antonyms.

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duty#Antonyms) does list *right* as an antonym of *duty*.

Comment: Lucky I presented a convincing argument based on *meaning* before I relied on thesaurus entries ;-)  - and also fascinating that Wiktionary doesn't list debit as an antonym of credit, even though I'd say they're opposites!